# Side by Side Form Field Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.3 and following the CSS documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) to implement a inline form-field.

My HTML is:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><%= f.label :login %>
      <%= f.text_field :login %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden"><input name="authenticity_token" value="**" type="hidden"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><label for="user_login">Login</label>
      <input id="user_login" name="user[login]" type="text"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br>
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
</form>  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
```

However my result is:
[image]

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you use?
Can you provide generated HTML?
Your closing tag SECTION is not closing it is opening a new section.

Comment: Assuming you are using an old version of Bootstrap (< 3.0), this would be correct so the first I would check would be any CSS applied to the elements, namely any padding being applied which is typically the culprit for grid columns breaking incorrectly.

Comment: Im using Bootstrap 3.0.3

Comment: I updated the question to include more information. I hope it could clarify a few things.

Comment: Please show the surrounding code--rendered HTML, not server-side stuff. This may be about the container the form is in, not the form itself.

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you have missed this class to your input controls: `class="form-control"`

Consider to add the placeholder and the `class="sr-only"` on the labels.

Ref: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden"><input name="authenticity_token" value="**" type="hidden"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><label lass="sr-only" for="user_login">Login</label>
      <input id="user_login" name="user[login]" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><label lass="sr-only" for="user_password">Password</label><br>
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button><form/>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/4vsDa/

Comment: Worked perfectly! Any suggestions on how can I implement this using embedded ruby using resource and sybmobols instead of describing each label?

Comment: @LeoCosta you are welcome; I can't understand your question, can you explain it deeper?

Comment: This code you suggested, which works, is the Generated HTML. If you take a look at the first code which I posted in the question, which is actually my html.erb file, you can see for example that I use f.label :login instead of label for=user_login.